# How to read all folders name in a directory using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to read all folder name in a directory. Folder name as like **2018_5_27**. Then will delete all folder without *this->date* folder will available.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and Jquery are client side. So it will be unsafe.
I think it's not correct approach for what you want to do.

You could implement a php function to call when you need. That function receive date, and you can delete all folders you want.

Comment: This application fully done by JQuery and HTML. So, I need to done it by javaScript or JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is not possible from client side, imagine what people could do if a when accessing to a website this one could delete your files.

Comment: This is not for website. This is for apps which is done by Framework7. So, I have to do it by javaScript or JQuery. 

- Thanks

Comment: It's the same you are on the client side and JS will not allow you to write or delete files. It would be a major security breach if it was possible.